How to avoid divergence phenomenon in Kalman Filter
According to this Kalman Filter algorithm in the book Kalman filtering and neural networks. The author says that computing the coverance matrix $P_k$ in this way:
$$P_k = (I-G_kH_k)P^-_k$$
Is bad because the $P_k$ can be negative-definite, which means it contains negative numbers.
The author later explains a walk around to this:

Hence, unless the numerical accuracy of the
algorithm is high enough, the matrix $P_k$ resulting from this computation
may not be nonnegative-definite. Such a situation is clearly unacceptable,
because $P_k$ represents a covariance matrix. The unstable behavior of the
Kalman filter, which results from numerical inaccuracies due to the use of
finite-wordlength arithmetic, is called the divergence phenomenon.
Arefined method of overcoming the divergence phenomenon is to use
numerically stable unitary transformations at every iteration of the Kalman
filtering algorithm [6]. In particular, the matrix $P_k$ is propagated in a
square-root form by using the Cholesky factorization
$$P_k = P^{\frac{1}{2}}_kP^{\frac{T}{2}}_k$$                         (1:31)
where $P^{\frac{1}{2}}_k$ is reserved for a lower-triangular matrix,
and $P^{\frac{T}{2}}_k$ transpose. In linear algebra, the Cholesky
factor $P^{\frac{1}{2}}_k$ is its  is commonly referred to as the
square root of the matrix $P_k$. Accordingly, any variant of the
Kalman filtering algorithm based on the Cholesky factorization is
referred  to as square-root filtering. The important point to note
here is that the  matrix product $P^{\frac{1}{2}}_kP^{\frac{T}{2}}_k$
much less likely to become indefinite, because the product of any
square matrix and its transpose is always positive definite. Indeed,
even in the presence of roundoff errors, the numerical  conditioning
of the Cholesky factor $P^{\frac{1}{2}}_k$ of $P_k$ itself.

Source: Page 11
Question:
So instead of computing the equation $P_k = (I-G_kH_k)P^-_k$, I should instead compute $P_k = P^{\frac{1}{2}}_kP^{\frac{T}{2}}_k$
So my question is: How can I use Cholesky Decomposition to compute $P_k = P^{\frac{1}{2}}_kP^{\frac{T}{2}}_k$

Isn't the method documented in [6] as refered by your source?

@AlexTP sorry, it's not documented.
